# How to override the JPopupMenu method show?

Tags: java, swing, overriding, jlist, jpopupmenu

my goal is to highlight a jlist item after a rightclick then show a jpopupmenu..
I read advice that overriding the method show is the way..
in my case i declare my jpopupmenu at the beginning of my class

```
     JPopupMenu popupMenu = new JPopupMenu();
     JMenuItem masterlist,settings;
```

then i have a method to set up my menuItems

```
    public void setPopupMenu(int depth//ignore this var){
    //popupMenu = new JPopupMenu();
    popupMenu.removeAll();

        masterlist = new JMenuItem("Masterlist");
        settings = new JMenuItem("Settings");

        //action for marsterlist
        masterlist.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            //stuff here
            }
        });
        //action for settings
        settings.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            //stuff here
            }
        });

        popupMenu.add(masterlist);
        popupMenu.add(settings);
 }
```

and my list is in a different method

```
list.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
list.setLayoutOrientation(JList.HORIZONTAL_WRAP);
list.setVisibleRowCount(-1);
list.setComponentPopupMenu(popupMenu);
```

I tried putting this on a mouseAdapter of my list but the popupmenu fires first and ignores highlighting...

```
   if ( SwingUtilities.isRightMouseButton(mouseEvent) )//highlight the right clicked item
                 {

                    int row = list.locationToIndex(mouseEvent.getPoint());
                    list.setSelectedIndex(row); 
                    String val = (String)list.getSelectedValue();
                    System.out.println(val);
                 }
```

i know that overriding is something like this

```
  popupmenu = new JPopupMenu(){
  @Override
  public void show(){}
  }
```

but i cant do that because i am manipulating the menuitems on a method...
or is there any other approach that anyone can suggest...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather then trying to modify the state of the `JPopupMenu`, why not simply modify the state of the menu item when you detect a right click...

[image: JList with right mouse selection and popup]

So, basically, I make use of the [Actions API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html) to define a menu item for a `JPopupMenu`, which allows it to register a `ListSelectionListener` to the underlying `JList`...

```
public class ShowItemAction extends AbstractAction {

    private JList list;

    public ShowItemAction(JList list) {
        this.list = new JList();
        putValue(NAME, "Showing ...");

        list.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {
            @Override
            public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
                if (!e.getValueIsAdjusting()) {
                    int index = list.getSelectedIndex();
                    String value = list.getSelectedValue().toString();
                    putValue(NAME, "Showing " + value + " @ " + index);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // The actual action to be performed when selected
    }

}
```

All this does is, when the selection is changed, is change the text (`NAME`) of the action, which changes the text of the menu item, based on the currently selected row.

When I create the `JList`, I assign it a `JPopupMenu` via the `setComponentPopupMenu` method, which means I no longer need to care about it and it will be displayed appropriately based on the current look and feel requirements

```
JList list = new JList(model);
JPopupMenu popupMenu = new JPopupMenu();
popupMenu.add(new ShowItemAction(list));
list.setComponentPopupMenu(popupMenu);
```

I then add a `MouseListener` to the `JList` which I use to change the row selection when you right click on the `JList`...

```
list.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        JList list = (JList)e.getComponent();
        if (SwingUtilities.isRightMouseButton(e)) {
            int row = list.locationToIndex(e.getPoint());
            list.setSelectedIndex(row);
        }
    }
});
```

This not entirely fool proof, as if you right click the `JList` while the popup is visible, the `MouseListener` doesn't appear to get notified :P

Runnable example...

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import static javax.swing.Action.NAME;
import javax.swing.DefaultListModel;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JPopupMenu;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionListener;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                DefaultListModel model = new DefaultListModel();
                model.addElement("One");
                model.addElement("Two");
                model.addElement("Three");
                model.addElement("Four");
                JList list = new JList(model);
                JPopupMenu popupMenu = new JPopupMenu();
                popupMenu.add(new ShowItemAction(list));
                list.setComponentPopupMenu(popupMenu);

                list.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

                    @Override
                    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                        if (SwingUtilities.isRightMouseButton(e)) {
                            int row = list.locationToIndex(e.getPoint());
                            list.setSelectedIndex(row);
                        }
                    }

                });

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new JScrollPane(list));
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class ShowItemAction extends AbstractAction {

        private JList list;

        public ShowItemAction(JList list) {
            this.list = new JList();
            putValue(NAME, "Showing ...");

            list.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {
                @Override
                public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
                    if (!e.getValueIsAdjusting()) {
                        int index = list.getSelectedIndex();
                        String value = list.getSelectedValue().toString();
                        putValue(NAME, "Showing " + value + " @ " + index);
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: it will take time to study and apply this.. i will update you as soon as possible.. btw thanks for fast response.

Comment: There might be a better solution, but this is the kind of thing I tend to use ;)

Comment: hey thanks.. what i did is override the mousePressed function just like what you did and put the setSelectedIndex()... also thanks for the explanation it helps a lot.